# SSAS- Dimension Attribute needs to be sorted

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas

In one of my SSAS- cube one attribute(inset_date) which is Date datatype and format is yyyy-mm-dd, when I checked in excel pivots it is not coming in order.
I have changed the order by property from name to key but it is not sorted,
Key  -- insert_date(date)
Name -- insert_date(wchar)
Value-- insert_date(date)
Can you please what other properties I have to change to sort the attribute of a dimension?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your well asked question.

Ordering attribute hierarchy in [SSAS](http://www.ssas-info.com/analysis-services-faq/28-design/89-how-do-you-order-dimension-attribute) can be done in four different ways

1. By Key
2. By name
3. By Other related attribute key.
4. By other related attribute name.
   By in order to activate ordering we need to set the property AttributeHierarchyOrdered=True.